# Host database online for android application

Tags: android, sql-server, database, sqlite, host

I am a beginner in android development,the database size of the application will be large,so it should be hosted online and i will query it from the application and make a sqlite database internal in the application..
 - Is it the best solution ?
 - How can i host a database online ?
 - What is the best type of database that i should use MYSQL or MSSQL   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to have huge database and planning to work on the online hosted system. Take the following tips:

1)You should first have server with the proper web service to process request from android application, so learn about Web Service programming and supporting the platform(Linux or Windows) of your server.

2) You should not bother about database, you can use what is more familiar to you and which support the platform of your server.

3)Finally you should learn about making http request from android application, you can start learning from [here](http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put)
.
Hope it help you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

To start things off, study Android and put more effort in your questions.

1. Yes, that is a viable option. Have your database hosted in your online server and have your app download it.
2. Subscribe to an online hosting service. If you don't want to pay yet since you're only starting to learn Android, you can host it via your local network using MAMP or XAMP.
3. Since the Android App will use SQLite 3, it's best if you used SQL in your server so the database structure and syntax wouldn't be too far.